# Sort the results in a foreach

Tags: php, sql, sql-order-by, average

if I have the following values ​​in a table:

table: `user`

id rating

1   5

2   4

1   3

2   2

obviously doing `SELECT * FROM USER`

I pull out all the values ​​of the user table, but if I wanted to calculate the average score of the two IDs, then for the id (sum the ratings) and division of the number that have been evaluated

ID: 1 = (5+3) / 2 = 4

ID: 2 = (4+2) / 2 = 3

and I wanted to sort these IDs based on their average value calculated later and not by query how could I do?

shows the users with the best score in order

Upload pic

[image: values]

my results:

```
global $wpdb;
$q = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare(" 


SELECT comment_id, avg(meta_value) avg_meta_value
FROM {$wpdb->prefix}commentmeta 


WHERE {$wpdb->prefix}commentmeta.meta_key = 'rating'
GROUP BY comment_id 
ORDER BY avg_meta_value desc")
            <?php foreach ($q as $r){ ?>
                <?php echo "{$r->comment_id}".'<br>'; ?>
            <?php } ?>
```

but if i make a join:

```
SELECT comment_id, avg(meta_value) avg_meta_value
FROM {$wpdb->prefix}commentmeta 

LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}comments
ON {$wpdb->prefix}commentmeta.comment_id = {$wpdb->prefix}comments.comment_ID

WHERE {$wpdb->prefix}commentmeta.meta_key = 'rating'
GROUP BY comment_id 
ORDER BY avg_meta_value desc")
```

not work anymore

Comment: You'll have to sort _before_ foreach - let the database do that (ORDER BY)

Comment: "and not by query" - Why not? Doing this in SQL sounds like the better option.

Comment: How posted table (picture) correspond to users table? Do you want to receive comment_it in order its average rating?

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev yes, I wrote user just to make people understand what the problem was, but if you check the question I changed as soon as I join it doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 1):

Use `avg()`:

```
select id, avg(rating) avg_rating from user group by id order by avg_rating desc
```